# LeetCode 1179: Reformat Department Table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a [LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/reformat-department-table/) for interviews.

What would be the most efficient way (time/space complexity) to write this MySQL query? Does the coding style follow the MySQL variable naming conventions?

#### Problem

Table: Department

```
+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| id            | int     |
| revenue       | int     |
| month         | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
```

(id, month) is the primary key of this table.

The table has information about the revenue of each department per month.

The month has values in ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"].

Write an SQL query to reformat the table such that there is a department id column and a revenue column for each month.

The query result format is in the following example:

Department table:

```
+------+---------+-------+
| id   | revenue | month |
+------+---------+-------+
| 1    | 8000    | Jan   |
| 2    | 9000    | Jan   |
| 3    | 10000   | Feb   |
| 1    | 7000    | Feb   |
| 1    | 6000    | Mar   |
+------+---------+-------+
```

Result table:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
| id   | Jan_Revenue | Feb_Revenue | Mar_Revenue | ... | Dec_Revenue |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
| 1    | 8000        | 7000        | 6000        | ... | null        |
| 2    | 9000        | null        | null        | ... | null        |
| 3    | null        | 10000       | null        | ... | null        |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----+-------------+
```

Note that the result table has 13 columns (1 for the department id + 12 for the months).

```
Create table If Not Exists Department (id int, revenue int, month varchar(5))
Truncate table Department
insert into Department (id, revenue, month) values ('1', '8000', 'Jan')
insert into Department (id, revenue, month) values ('2', '9000', 'Jan')
insert into Department (id, revenue, month) values ('3', '10000', 'Feb')
insert into Department (id, revenue, month) values ('1', '7000', 'Feb')
insert into Department (id, revenue, month) values ('1', '6000', 'Mar')
```

#### Attempt

```
SELECT id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'jan' THEN revenue END) AS Jan_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'feb' THEN revenue END) AS Feb_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'mar' THEN revenue END) AS Mar_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'apr' THEN revenue END) AS Apr_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'may' THEN revenue END) AS May_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'jun' THEN revenue END) AS Jun_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'jul' THEN revenue END) AS Jul_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'aug' THEN revenue END) AS Aug_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'sep' THEN revenue END) AS Sep_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'oct' THEN revenue END) AS Oct_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'nov' THEN revenue END) AS Nov_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'dec' THEN revenue END) AS Dec_Revenue
FROM department
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

#### Reference

[1179. Reformat Department Table](https://leetcode.com/problems/reformat-department-table/discuss/)

Comment: I would reject the premise of the question on the basis that the optimal solution would almost certainly be to handle the display aspects of this problem in application code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably use `MAX` as the aggregate function, not `SUM`, assuming a given `id` and month would only have one record for revenue.  That being said, if you want to use `SUM`, then your `CASE` expressions should have an else condition with zero revenue:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Jan_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Feb_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Mar' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Mar_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Apr' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Apr_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'May' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS May_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Jun' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Jun_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Jul' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Jul_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Aug' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Aug_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Sep' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Sep_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Oct' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Oct_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Nov' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Nov_Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month = 'Dec' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Dec_Revenue
FROM department
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id;
```

Comment: The major issue here is that some `id` values might have any records/data for certain months.  In this case, you would like to report a revenue of zero.  Using `SUM` with zero for the else condition is one way to do this.  If you expect all months would always have values for all `id`, then just use `MAX` with no else condition.

Comment: . . The desired results explicitly have `NULL`, so no `ELSE` clause should be used.

Comment: @Gordon Perhaps I misread the question, but I interpreted the results shown as what the OP already has, not necessarily the "right" answer expected by Leet.